# How do you search a UITable with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm working on a project and I want the user to be able to search a list on a UITableView. I've added the search bar and connected it to the search display controller. I have no idea how to actually search the list and grab the data from parse, filter it, set it to the PFUser of toUser, and display it. Anyone know how to do this?

Here's the code where I save the message:

```
 if (toUser!= nil){
       app[@"toUser"]=toUser;



    }
        [app save];
```

Here are some code snippets for the table view:

This displays the users and filters out the current user:

```
 ParseExampleAppDelegate *delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    users = [[query findObjects] mutableCopy];
    for(PFUser *user in users){
        if ([user.objectId isEqualToString:delegate.applicationUser.objectId]){
            [users removeObject:user];
            break;
        }


    }

    [users removeObject:delegate.applicationUser];
    NSLog(@"all user: %lu",users.count);
    [self.usersTable setDelegate:self];
    [self.usersTable setDataSource:self];
    [self.usersTable reloadData];

        [self.usersTable reloadData];
```

Some methods for the table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"userCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFObject *tempObject = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.text= [tempObject objectForKey:@"username"];

    return cell;

    NSMutableArray *filteredStrings;
    BOOL isFiltered;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"users:%lu",[users count]);
    return [users count];
}
```

Thanks for your help,

armanb21

Comment: Ehhh. As this is possible, I think by filtering and adding a new object every time a keyword has changed will increase your API requests. So for a few users this is fine but think about a large scale of using this feature simultaneously within the same 60 seconds you will start receiving request errors.

Comment: I would recommend saving whatever your trying to search into an array or dictionary and  through those.

Comment: @soulshined how do you add something from a Parse query into a dictionary or array? Also, how would I remove the results that aren't what the user searched for using a dictionary? Thanks for your help, armanb21.